# Select most occurring attribute in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NewsID, UserID, PoliticianID
FROM Votes
WHERE UserID = 1010
```

And result looks like this:

```
NewsID | UserID | PoliticianID
40       1010     3
40       1010     10
38       1010     27
39       1010     27
40       1010     35
```

Is there a way to get number `27` from my example above with SQL?
I would like to get `PoliticianID` that has been voted most by a user.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? This should be easy enough to achieve using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Comment: I tried but couldn't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: you say you want to get `27` but you than say you want the most voted `PoliticianID` which is actually `35` , i m a little confused about what you are trying to achive.

Comment: I don't see where you've got that most voted politician is `35` as he was voted 1 time vs `27` that was voted twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

I have created a new TEMP Table that holds your query and gives you the result as required.

```
SELECT TOP 1 PoliticianID, COUNT(PoliticianID) AS CNT
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT NewsID, UserID, PoliticianID
     FROM Votes
     WHERE UserID = 1010) AS tempT
GROUP BY PoliticianID
ORDER BY CNT DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying something like this, but I guess I over complicated my query. This works great.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Votes
WHERE PoliticianID IN
(
    SELECT PoliticianID
    FROM votes 
    GROUP BY PoliticianID
    HAVING  COUNT(NewsID) = (SELECT MAX(NCount)
                             FROM
                             (
                               SELECT COUNT(*) NCount
                               FROM Votes
                               GROUP BY PoliticianID, UserId
                             ) t)
)
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db1e2/6)

**Or:** With a CTE:

```
;WITH TheMostOccurredIds
AS
(
  SELECT PoliticianID
  FROM votes 
  GROUP BY PoliticianID
  HAVING  COUNT(NewsID) = (SELECT MAX(NCount)
                           FROM
                           (
                             SELECT COUNT(*) NCount
                             FROM Votes
                             GROUP BY PoliticianID, userID
                           ) t)
  )
SELECT *
FROM Votes
WHERE PoliticianID IN (SELECT PoliticianID FROM TheMostOccurredIds) ;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo With CTE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db1e2/13)

---

### Update

**Note that:** the solution above, will give you all the most occurrance Ids, and this will work fine if there are not duplicate max values. However, If you want to get the TOP one, in case there were a lot of ids with the same max number like in the example you posted in your comment, you can use the ranking function [**`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) like this:

```
;WITH VotesCountCTE
AS
(
  SELECT [UserID], [PoliticianID], COUNT(*) votesCount
  FROM votes
  GROUP BY [UserID], [PoliticianID]
),TopVotes
AS
(
  SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY votescount) rownum
  FROM VotesCountCTE
 )
SELECT *
FROM TopVotes
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/465ef/6)

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I run your query I once again get 5 rows as a result. I get the same result as if I were to just `SELECT DISTINCT...` as in my example above, but with getting all the table fields with `*`, and not restricting it to my above 3.

Comment: @ttkalec This should work fine, and it is working fine in the sample demo in my answer. Can you please setup a demo example of your actual query you are using explaining this issue in [this url](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db1e2/13) and if you want to select only 3 columns, you can list them in the `SELECT` list instead of `SELECT *`.

Comment: I know about `SELECT *`. [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/465ef/1), I've edited your example so you can see what I get when I run your query. Thank you again for your time. @Talha managed to solve my problem, so you don't have to waste any more of your time.

Comment: @ttkalec - Yes, you are right, my solution works only for non duplicate values, but in the example you posted, which contains duplicate max values you have to use `TOP` like in @Talha solution. **BTW*: I am not wasting my time. I am just learning like you.

Comment: Your comment just put a smile on my face. Stackoverflow really has a great community :)

Comment: @ttkalec - Yes it is a great community. Any way back to time wasting :). See my edit. This is another solution, almost like the talha solution.

Comment: This approach works well. I'm interested why have you used `WHERE rownum=1` instead of `SELECT TOP 1 *`?

Comment: @ttkalec In this case, they are the same. I just familiar with this way. However, in other cases , where you specify a `PARTITION BY` clause inside the `OVER` clause `TOP` won't work(Won't get the desired results). This function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ...)` is very useful read more about it and other ranking and analytical functions in T SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work...

```
SELECT TOP 1 NewsID, UserID, PoliticianID, COUNT(PoliticianID)
FROM Votes
WHERE UserID = 1010
GROUP BY NewsID, UserID, PoliticianID
ORDER BY COUNT(PoliticianID) DESC
```

Comment: No, I get this result: `40|1010|10|5`. Column names are as you defined them in your solution.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: No worries. Tnx for your answer anyway :)